# AngularJS i18n: ngLocale FIRSTDAYOFWEEK and WEEKENDRANGE

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

Somewhere in the v1.4.0-betas, Angular i18n files acquired some new attributes like `DATETIME_FORMATS.FIRSTDAYOFWEEK`.  [Latest version as of now](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/i18n/).

Does anyone understand how `FIRSTDAYOFWEEK` and `WEEKENDRANGE` work?  From my observation, here's what I think was intended

1. `DATETIME_FORMATS.DAY` always starts on Sunday (consistent with 0 = Sunday in javascript), no matter what day of the week is considered the first day of the week in that locale
2. `DATETIME_FORMATS.FIRSTDAYOFWEEK` should indicate the first day of the week in the locale, so that if it's 0, the week starts on Sunday, 1 = Monday and so on.
3. `DATETIME_FORMATS.WEEKENDRANGE` should be the days of the week that are considered weekend days in the locale

My problems are that

- `DATETIME_FORMATS.FIRSTDAYOFWEEK` for [en-au](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/i18n/angular-locale_en-au.js) is `6`.  That would be Saturday, and the first day of the week isn't Saturday here in Australia (they [argue about Sunday or Monday](http://blogs.news.com.au/couriermail/parenting/index.php/couriermail/comments/so_which_day_is_the_first_day_of_the_week) being the start)
- `DATETIME_FORMATS.WEEKENDRANGE` for en-au is `[5, 6]` and Friday isn't a weekend day here either (despite the fact that workers slack off and drink beer in the afternoons).

So are there just a bunch of errors in the files?  Or do I not understand the scheme being implemented here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ngLocale` files, ["Monday is day 0 as specified by ISO-8601"](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11900)

...as opposed to Javascript, where `Date.prototype.getDay()` returns 0 for Sunday. Watch out!

I asked for this to be added to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the ISO 8601 states that Monday is 1 not 0 as it is declared in angular's i18n.

3.2.2 - The week calendar - Table 2 - Calendar days

```
| **Ordinal day number in the week** | **Calendar day name** |
| --- | --------- |
|   1 | Monday    |
|   2 | Tuesday   |
|   3 | Wednesday |
|   4 | Thursday  |
|   5 | Friday    |
|   6 | Saturday  |
|   7 | Sunday    |
```